# How do I make the font size be the same across different width pages (on iPhone)?

Tags: html, css

I have three webpages using the same font size (1.875rem heading text & 0.96875rem body text), but they all look different on the iPhone.

[Page 1 iPhone Screenshot](http://www.test59.epizy.com/page1.jpg)

[Page 2 iPhone Screenshot](http://www.test59.epizy.com/page2.jpg)

[Page 3 iPhone Screenshot](http://www.test59.epizy.com/page3.jpg)

I want the font size in Pages 2 and 3 to look like Page 1.

Everything looks good on my laptop. The HTML code for each page appears below:

[Page 1 HTML](http://www.test59.epizy.com/page1.html)

[Page 2 HTML](http://www.test59.epizy.com/page2.html)

[Page 3 HTML](http://www.test59.epizy.com/page3.html)

How can I fix this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: adding a viewport meta tag can help often. Add this: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` to your head and it could be fixed.

Comment: Thank you korki, Pyry Lahtinen, and Oliver Hnat. I changed the scale to 0.5 and everything looks good now. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @korki said, add this to your `<head>` tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: thanks for the mention! it's always good to have such a meta tag specified, because it will resolve many problems (specialy with responsive design)

Comment: Thank you korki, Pyry Lahtinen, and Oliver Hnat. I changed the scale to 0.5 and everything looks good now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you are just starting with html, it's a good practice to make a layout.html and put everything that's same on all pages in that file, it's called templating, I always just put this inside the head [Here is a page, where they explain it pretty well](https://codeburst.io/jinja-2-explained-in-5-minutes-88548486834e). I always just `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` in the `<head>` of all of my templates

Comment: Thank you korki, Pyry Lahtinen, and Oliver Hnat. I changed the scale to 0.5 and everything looks good now. Thank you!